# A good way to add a "radioactive" button with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I use CSS3 to make my buttons "radioactive" with a glow around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am in a real hurry to leave but made a basic 1, would have made a real clear but as I said am getting late but you can check out a demo here..hope you like it..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wd3fQ/)

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="container glow" value="Hello" />
```

CSS

```
.container{
    animation:glow 7s;
    -moz-animation:glow 7s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:glow 7s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation:demo 7s; /* Opera */
    animation:glow 7s infinite;
    margin: 30px;
}

@keyframes glow {
    0% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;}
    50% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #B2FF54;}
    100% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;}
}

@-moz-keyframes glow /* Firefox */ {
    0% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;}
    50% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #B2FF54;}
    100% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow /* Safari and Chrome */ {
    0% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;}
    50% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #B2FF54;}
    100% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;}
}

@-o-keyframes glow /* Opera */ {
    0% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;}
    50% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #B2FF54;}
    100% {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px#B2FF54;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #B2FF54;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you use Google before you post here. (Try CSS3 button glow)
My first result was: http://www.zurb.com/playground/radioactive-buttons

Comment: You don't have any hats.

Answer (score 0):

Use box-shadow property:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #123456; 
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #123456; 
box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #123456;
```